# Cannot resolve the fragment container's id while adding fragment to an activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public void setFragment(){
    RegisterFragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I am trying to add `Fragment` to an `Activity`, but it is showing the error,

> "cannot resolve the symbol fragment_container"

But, I have already defined the fragment container in `xml` layout file.

Comment: Make sure `fragment_container` lies in the layout file of an `Activity`.

Comment: Add your xml code

Comment: But i already did it.

Comment: XML Code:<FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

    </FrameLayout>